# Как вывести матрицу в виде поля

Tags: javascript

---

```
let haystack2 = 
[
  ['#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
  ['#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#']
];
console.log(haystack2.flat(Infinity))
```

---

Необходимо получить такой вывод в консоли: [image: Нужно чтобы вывелось]

Comment: А зачем вам, собственно говоря, это надо?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function cLog(n) {
  let str = '';    
  for (let i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
    str += [1,n].includes(i) ? Array(n).fill('#',0,n).join(' ') + '\n' : '#' + Array(n).fill(' ',0,n-2).join(' ') + '#\n';    
  }
  return str; 
}

console.log(cLog(5));
console.log(cLog(7));
console.log(cLog(10));
```